# Input field emptied on jQuery's slideUp()/slideDown()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an input field with some text, and I am trying to toggle its visibility. The problem I'm running into is that after toggling slide animations on the field, its text is invisible.
When the field is brought into focus though, the text is visible again.

I've tested this on Safari/IE/FF and the input text stays visible, but I cannot figure out why Chrome is acting so odd.

http://jsfiddle.net/f63Et/1/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that jQuery sets the display of the input to `inline-block` when it does an `.slideDown()` and that makes Chrome render it incorrectly.

You have a couple of options, for example [wrap the input in a div](http://jsfiddle.net/f63Et/7/), or [set the display to block](http://jsfiddle.net/f63Et/6/)

Comment: The one time Chrome acts oddly out of all the browsers..
Your answer pretty much covers both workarounds, with a reason to boot, so I'll mark it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to manually focus it by putting in the slideDown()'s callback:

```
$(this).focus()
```

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't answer the question of why Chrome behaves strangely, but, as a workaround, if you enclose your input in a div:

```
<div id="text"><input type="text" /></div>
```

Then `slideToggle` the div:

```
$(document).on('click', '#slide', function() {
    $('#text').slideToggle();
});
```

That appears to work in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

As a variant you can use `$('input').toggle('slow')`